# parse a list of json string with PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a list of JSON  with a pyspark dataframe.
You will find below my input data and my aim is to get a dataframe with two columns user (string ) and ips Array[Sting].

`sampleJson = [ ('{"user":100, "ips" : ["191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.99"]}',),  ('{"user":101, "ips" : ["191.168.192.102", "191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]}',),  ('{"user":102, "ips" : ["191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.107"]}',),  ('{"user":103, "ips" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.107", "191.168.192.101"]}',),  ('{"user":104, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.102", "191.168.192.99"]}',),  ('{"user":105, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.96"]}',),  ]`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome. What have you trie so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`from_json`** function by **`defining schema`**.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sampleJson = [ ('{"user":100, "ips" : ["191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.99"]}',),  ('{"user":101, "ips" : ["191.168.192.102", "191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]}',),  ('{"user":102, "ips" : ["191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.101", "191.168.192.105", "191.168.192.107"]}',),  ('{"user":103, "ips" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.107", "191.168.192.101"]}',),  ('{"user":104, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.102", "191.168.192.99"]}',),  ('{"user":105, "ips" : ["191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.99", "191.168.192.100", "191.168.192.96"]}',),  ]

df1=spark.createDataFrame(sampleJson)

sch=StructType([StructField('user', StringType(), False),StructField('ips',ArrayType(StringType()))])

df1.withColumn("n",from_json(col("_1"),sch)).select("n.*").show(10,False)
#+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|user|ips                                                                 |
#+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|100 |[191.168.192.101, 191.168.192.103, 191.168.192.96, 191.168.192.99]  |
#|101 |[191.168.192.102, 191.168.192.105, 191.168.192.103, 191.168.192.107]|
#|102 |[191.168.192.105, 191.168.192.101, 191.168.192.105, 191.168.192.107]|
#|103 |[191.168.192.96, 191.168.192.100, 191.168.192.107, 191.168.192.101] |
#|104 |[191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.102, 191.168.192.99]   |
#|105 |[191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.99, 191.168.192.100, 191.168.192.96]   |
#+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+


#schema

df1.withColumn("n",from_json(col("_1"),sch)).select("n.*").printSchema()
#root
# |-- user: string (nullable = true)
# |-- ips: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: thanks you so much , but i  really  didn,t undestand why you put the .* in  the select statement. I try to test without and i had another results.